How to Intercept and Modify JavaScript Responses Before Execution Using Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP)
I'm working on a project where I need to intercept JavaScript code that the browser receives but prevent it from executing immediately. I want to modify the JavaScript code to inject a custom worker navigator before it executes. I'm using Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) and undetected-chromedriver (nodriver) for this task.
Specifically, I'm looking to:

Intercept the JavaScript response from the server.
Modify the response to include my custom code.
Continue with the modified response, allowing the browser to execute it.

def intercept_request(tab, event):
event_data = RequestPaused.from_json(event)
request_id = event_data.request_id
resource_type = event_data.resource_type

if resource_type == ResourceType.SCRIPT:
    # Get the response body
    response_body, _ = await tab.send(get_response_body(request_id))

    modified_js_code = f"""
    (function() {{
        console.log('Injecting script to simulate an Android environment V35');
        if (self.__injected_worker_emulator) return;
        self.__injected_worker_emulator = true;

        console.log('Injecting worker script to emulate device properties and intercept fetch requests');

        function emulateWorker() {{
            console.log('Emulating Worker environment');

            console.log('self.navigator.userAgent before:', self.navigator.userAgent);
            Object.defineProperty(self.navigator, 'userAgent', {{
                get: function() {{ return "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"; }},
                configurable: true
            }});
            console.log('self.navigator.userAgent after:', self.navigator.userAgent);
        
            console.log('self.navigator.platform before:', self.navigator.platform);
            Object.defineProperty(self.navigator, 'platform', {{
                get: function() {{ return "Linux arm81"; }},
                configurable: true
            }});
            console.log('self.navigator.platform after:', self.navigator.platform);
        
            console.log('self.navigator.hardwareConcurrency before:', self.navigator.hardwareConcurrency);
            Object.defineProperty(self.navigator, 'hardwareConcurrency', {{
                get: function() {{ return 8; }},
                configurable: true
            }});
            console.log('self.navigator.hardwareConcurrency after:', self.navigator.hardwareConcurrency);
        
            console.log('self.navigator.deviceMemory before:', self.navigator.deviceMemory);
            Object.defineProperty(self.navigator, 'deviceMemory', {{
                get: function() {{ return 8; }},
                configurable: true
            }});
            console.log('self.navigator.deviceMemory after:', self.navigator.deviceMemory);
        
            console.log('self.navigator.userAgentData before:', self.navigator.userAgentData);
            Object.defineProperty(self.navigator, 'userAgentData', {{
                get: function() {{ return []; }},
                configurable: true
            }});
            console.log('self.navigator.userAgentData after:', self.navigator.userAgentData);

            const originalFetch = fetch;
            fetch = async function(...args) {{
                console.log('Intercepted fetch:', args);
                const response = await originalFetch(...args);
                // Modify response here if needed
                return response;
            }};
        }}

        emulateWorker();

        // Original script content
        {response_body}
    }})();
    """

    await tab.send(cdp.fetch.fulfill_request(
        requestId=request_id,
        responseCode=200,
        responseHeaders=event_data.response_headers,
        body=modified_js_code
    ))
else:
    await tab.send(cdp.fetch.continue_request(requestId=request_id))

async def main():
browser = await uc.start(headless=False)
tab = await browser.get("about:blank")

# Enable network tracking and set request interception for responses
await tab.send(cdp.network.enable())
await tab.send(cdp.fetch.enable(patterns=[RequestPattern(url_pattern="*", request_stage=InterceptionStage.HEADERS_RECEIVED)]))

# Add network event handler
tab.add_handler(cdp.fetch.RequestPaused, lambda event: asyncio.create_task(intercept_request(tab, event)))

await browser.get('https://example.com')

print("Listening for responses. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
try:
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(222)  # Keep the script running
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

